# Using JQuery to delete inline attributes in a table

Tags: jquery

First and foremost here is the code I am targeting:

table width="100%" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="5" border="1" style="margin-top: 30px; border: solid 1px #999999;"

I want to remove the border attributes using jquery from the table.  I have hundreds of tables with this same set of code and want to experiment with different looks.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that you have two references to the elements border. One as an attribute on the element and another one in the inline style attribute.

You can use jQuery's [`removeAttr()`](http://api.jquery.com/removeattr/) function to remove attributes from DOM elements. With this you  will be able to remove the `border="1"` attribute.

```
$("#table_element").removeAttr( "border" );
```

Alternatively, you could just set the border attribute to zero. For this, you would use the [`attr()` function](http://api.jquery.com/attr/):

```
$("#table_element").attr( "border", 0 );
```

In addition what you are wanting to do is edit the element's CSS properties because your element also has some inline styles.

For this you can use jQuery's [`css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/) function and set the border property to "none".

```
$("#table_element").css( "border", "none");
```

Comment: So I am kind of new to jquery, I know how to add classes, perform hides and shows, add switchs, and do binds but I still can't get this to work. In your examples is "#table_element" referred to as a placeholder or is this the exact code?  It doesn't seem to be working.  I am using a previous developers tables in our storefront so I had no control over how this was coded originally.  Not very good coding if you ask me.

Comment: No this is not the exact code. I gave `#table_element` as an example. It would require your table element to have an `id` attribute of `table_element`. You could use any jQuery selector to identify your element, classes, id's or any other attribute that sets the table element aside from the others.

Comment: Thanks.  I will have to find a way to select all tables that have that same pattern of text then.

Comment: If you have more than one element, I'd recommend finding a way to give them all the same class. Then you can use the [class selector](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/) to target all of the elements at once. Selecting tables according to their textual content might be a bit tricky.

Comment: I was able to remove the css but not the attribute so I still have borders around each individual cell.

Comment: @user3203552 - Check out the updates I made to my answer - I believe that it will solve your issue.